# Displaying Image Inside of Original GUI Frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a GUI form called `SimpleGUI` that is just a single `JPanel`. My goal is to display my URL image inside of the that `JPanel`.
When I try to add the image, I don't get an error, but nothing displays. The image DOES display if I create a new `JFrame` and add my `JPanel` to that. But then I have two Windows open.

How can I display my image in my original `SimpleGUI` form? (Code below)

Thank you!

```
public class SimpleGUI extends JFrame {
private JPanel imagesPanel;
//private JFrame mainFrame;

public SimpleGUI() throws IOException {
    super("GUI Page");
    setContentPane(imagesPanel);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

    //mainFrame = new JFrame();



    imagesPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    imagesPanel.setBounds(0,0,200,200);


    //mainFrame.add(imagesPanel);
    //mainFrame.setVisible(true);


    BufferedImage img1 = null;

    try
    {
        URL url1 = new URL("http://cosplayidol.otakuhouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/s-1-1.jpg");

        URLConnection conn1 = url1.openConnection();
        conn1.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
        InputStream in1 = conn1.getInputStream();

        img1 = ImageIO.read(in1);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    JLabel wIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img1));
    imagesPanel.add(wIcon);

  }
}
```

Main method:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here

    try {
        SimpleGUI simpleGUI = new SimpleGUI();
    } catch (IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your other code as well? The working code that creates a 2nd window? I see a lot of potential for things going wrong in the current code listing and I bet you're doing something slightly differently, and correctly, when you create the 2nd window.

Comment: To produce the second window, just remove all of the //s. Creating a new mainFrame, and adding the imagesPanel to that jFrame is what works.

Comment: can we see the class with your main method.  I can see you have a label at what point are you adding it to the frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code at the top of your method should be at the end. This should fix the problem

```
setContentPane(imagesPanel);
pack();
setVisible(true);
```

Edit: As well as fixing the problem, I should have explained why this fixes the problem. The issue is when you called pack() at the beginning of the method, nothing has been added to the imagePanel, and so the return value of `getPreferredSize()` is going to be very small / (0,0). After adding your Components, it can be sized appropriately